# Django all-auth get facebook profile pic

Tags: django

I have auth setup with all-auth. Is it possible using all-auth make a query to fb to get a link to profile pic ?

If not - what is proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I use python social auth and connected to facebook, google, twitter and vkontakte. Whenever I do a signin request I get back a response which is converted to dictionary object by this module. And all of this providers send profile pic url within that response. Try to print that response object and you should find what you are looking for.